# Problem with the installation of AMD ProRender in Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, add-on, radeon-prorender-render-engine

[image]Good day, I'm new in this community but I'm using Blender since two years.
I have tried to install the AMD ProRender in Blender 2.8 because on Mac it is the only way to use an AMD card.
When I active the add-on in the add-on list Blender give this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call)
File "/private/var/folder/2w/_npvfg1n7f55sw55vdlh2t4c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/D64D4A5A-5BD4-42E2_a4D4_CA17F82F1D45/d/Blender 2.8.app/Resources/2.80/scriptes/modules/addon_utiles.py", line 384, in enable mod.register()
FIle "/Users/Usernname/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.80/scripts/addons/rprblender/_init_.py", line 111, inn register
bpy.utils.register_class(RPREngine)
ValueError: expected RenderEngine, RPREngine class "view_update" function to have 3 args, found 2
```

Can someone help me please?

I searched only but nothing helped me

Comment: what *is* the error you are getting?

Comment: @David -- I'm getting ```WARNING rpr.engine.init [404]:  ('Plugin is not registered', WindowsPath('C:/Users/James/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/3.6/scripts/addons/rprblender/HybridPro.dll``` in the console